# Where to create OAuth users with cemerick/friend in Clojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I finally got OAuth workflows working for Twitter and Facebook logins on my Clojure Compojure project, but I need to handle new users. Where in the Friend workflow should I be  creating non-existent users in my data store? Inside `credential-fn` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. The `credential-fn` from one of my project looks right now something like:

```
(defn linkedin-auth [{access-token :access-token :as m}]
    (let [options      {:query-params {:oauth2_access_token access-token
                                      :format "json"}}
          account-info (http-json "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~" options)
          email        (http-json "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/email-address" options)]
    (register-or-load-from-db
       {:roles #{::user}
        :identity email
        :name (str (:firstName account-info) " " (:lastName account-info))}))))
```

And the workflow config:

```
(oauth2/workflow {:client-config linkedin-client-config
                  :uri-config    linkedin-uri-config
                  :credential-fn #'linkedin-auth
                  :login-uri     "/linkedinlogin"})
```

Comment: Thanks, @dAni. How would I access `:session`, or the currently signed in user from the `credential-fn` so that I can associate their identifier with an existing account, if they are already signed in?

Comment: perhaps I can achieve this by adding an additional workflow fn that parses the output of various providers' credential-fn's?

Comment: the `credential-fn` has to accept one parameter, which will contain the user credentials map. The user credentials map depend on the authentication method used. In the case of friend-oauth2, the map contains the access-token that then you can use to request additional info from the oauth provider (as you can see in my example). The result of the credential-fn ends up as part of the session information